# filter_at does not work when filtering for any variable that does NOT meet a criteria

Tags: r, dplyr, data-management

I'm trying to use dplyr's filter_at to filter out any person who was terminated at any point. However, it keeps giving me the wrong answer.

Here's a sample dataset:

```
problem <- tibble(name = c("Sally", "Frank", "Joe"),
                  status1 = c("On Staff", "On Staff", "On Staff"),
                  status2 = c("On Staff", "Term", "On Staff"),
                  status3 = c("On Staff", "Term", "Term"),
                  status4 = c("Promoted", "Rehired", "Term"))
```

As you can see, I have many variables that start with status, so I've tried filter_at all variables that contain status:

```
problem %>%
filter_at(vars(contains("status")), any_vars(. != "Term))
```

Unfortunately, it yields this unhelpful result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  name  status1  status2  status3  status4 
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 Sally On Staff On Staff On Staff Promoted
2 Frank On Staff Term     Term     Rehired 
3 Joe   On Staff On Staff Term     Term
```

Instead, I want the end product to look like this:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  name  status1  status2  status3  status4 
  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
1 Sally On Staff On Staff On Staff Promoted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `all_vars` instead of `any_vars` here with the same condition.  It checks for each of the columns in a row that it doesn't have the 'Term' element and if all the columns doesn't have it, return that row

```
problem %>%
   filter_at(vars(contains("status")), all_vars(. != "Term"))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#  name  status1  status2  status3  status4 
#  <chr> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    <chr>   
#1 Sally On Staff On Staff On Staff Promoted
```

---

In the OP's code, `any_vars`, is checking if any of the columns in each row doesn't have "Term" and it is satisified in all the rows